# Creating textboxes below "var Select_For_Multiple_Choices" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function AddingTextBoxes(){

var NumOfText=$("#NumOfTextBoxes").val();

$('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').empty();

for(i=1; i<=NumOfText; i++){

var ipBoxName="MyInput"+i;

var txtBoxAutoNumbering="<input type='text' name='textbx[]' style='width:50px;'         value="+i+" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBoxAutoNumbering);

var txtBox="<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBox);

var Select_SelectionOptions="<select id='SelectOption'><option>Text_Box</option>    <option>Text_Area</option><option>Radio_Button</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(Select_SelectionOptions);

var Select_For_Multiple_Choices="<button type='button' onclick='ChildTxtBoxes()'         id='ABC'>Click for child selections</button><br><br>";     
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(Select_For_Multiple_Choices);

}




return false;

/*for(var i=0; i<NumOfText; i++){
var x=1;
NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes.innerHTML=NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes.innerHTML+"<br>AAA "+x+"<input     type='text' name='mytext'/>";
x++;

}
return false;*/
}

function ChildTxtBoxes(){

var txtBox="<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBox);


}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<form >
<div id="PHPForms" >
<!--Designing PHP forms dynamically-->
<label>Form Heading</label><input type="text"/><br><br>
<label>Number of text boxes would needed</label><input id="NumOfTextBoxes" type="text"/>
<button id="A" onclick=" return AddingTextBoxes()">Click</button>
<div id="NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes" name="Texty">



</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code once I clicked button related to "var Select_For_Multiple_Choices" variable, I shold display a text-box right below the clicked button.. Likewise whenever the button is the text-box should be shown below that button... Bt in my code though it creates a text-box it shows aftr all the text boxes.... Hw I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .after() to insert after the found element. So something like this:

```
$(button).after(content);
```

Comment: $(Child_Btn+i).after("<input id='TxtID' type='text' name='textbx[]'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

Can I put button parameter like this... If I adjestted the button which finishes with  i...

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: What did u mean by button? is it the tag or do I need to put its id or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your code to work as expected by passing the execution context (`this`) to the function ChildTxtBoxes like: `ChildTxtBoxes(this)`. You have to modify your function to:

```
function ChildTxtBoxes(button) {
    var txtBox = "<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>"
    $(button).after(txtBox);
}
```

notice the use of the execution context(`this`) to identify the button that was clicked and the use of `.after()` to insert a textbox after the button as Vlad suggested.

To be honest, I don't fully understand the keyword `this` to explain how and why it works. You can read up more on [JavaScript “this” keyword here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1179865)

[Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HWE2T/2/)